# How do I run an effective IT-Sec Team Meeting?

Tags: people-management

I'm looking at revamping how our weekly team meetings are conducted.  There is not a lot of techies in the meeting as the majority of operational work is outsourced.

I'm not looking for answers about keep time limits, document meeting minutes, more around the content of the meeting and how to make it engaging and beneficial for everyone involved.

What do you do? What are the best parts of your info sec meeting?

Our current format is.

- Discuss any open action items and their status
- General management update (general business news/issues/initiatives)
- Review of 27001, PCI schedules
- Security incident discussions
- Highlight any issues / risks / threats
- discuss any due audit items
- discuss improvement opportunities
- Items requiring escalation / approval
- Round table update on what we are all working on
- any health and safe issues
- open to other business

Comment: I'm not sure this question is actually to do with security. It may be better suited over at workplace SE. If there is a specific question which is answerable objectively, please edit that in and we may be able to reopen.